# How do I remove empty <p> elements?

Tags: php, regex

I have the follow regex:

```
$html = '<p></p><p>Lorem ispum...</p><p>  </p><p>;nbsp</p>';
$pattern = "/<p[^>]*><\\/p[^>]*>/";
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $html );
```

This only removes the `<p>` tag if it's actually empty, i.e. `<p></p>`. How do I remove it if it has some other invisible copy in it, such as `&nbsp;`?

Comment: `;nbsp` or `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Try `echo preg_replace('~<p[^<]*>(?>\s|(?R))*</p>~u', '', html_entity_decode($html));` - this should work if you have correct HTML entities. If not, you will need to replace them "manually" (with a list, perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible kinds of whitespace and even more possibilities for "empty" (e.g., is `<p><em></em></p>` empty? Or not?).

Also consider the possibility of having `<p class="para">` or `<p id="chief">`.

Much depends on where the text comes from. Microsoft Word will output `&#160;`'s in some circumstances *(I could and did unremember them -- sorry)*.

A [reasonable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/1428679) possibility for now might be to use a regex such as `#<p>(\\s|&nbsp;)*</p>#mis'` to match multiple empty lines.

But keep in mind that this kind of requisite tends to rapidly become [unreasonable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1428679) - for example the class part might force you to use `#<p[^>]*>(\\s|&nbsp;)*</p>#mis'` and so on - so, you might want to start looking into a XML parser instead.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by backspace, you mean whitespace, and that `;nbsp&` should be `&nbsp;` and propose:

```
$pattern = "/<p[^>]*>(\s|&nbsp;)*<\\/p[^>]*>/";
```

`\s` mathes any whitespace character

The pattern mathes `\s` OR (`|`) `&nbsp;` ANY (`*`) number of times inside the `<p>` tags.

Comment: Note that <p/> will not be removed in this case.